# Laravel 5 Route Caching Issues

Tags: caching, routes, laravel-5

I added some route filters, and then ran route:cache. The filters work great if I don't run the cache command but definitely are not being called with route caching enabled.

Am I doing something wrong or do filters not work with the new route caching mechanism?

Please see the example below:

```
Route::filter('something', function () {
    dd('Made It Here!');
});
Route::when('something*', 'something');
```

When I add this without running route:cache or after running route:clear the matched route prints 'Made It Here!'. If I run route:cache and then go to the route, I get nothing.

Comment: Can you add some specific code that you are running and describe in what way you are not seeing the results you expect?

Comment: I updated the question to include an example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's works fine for me.
My routes.php:

```
Route::filter('something', function () {
    dd('Made It Here!');
});
Route::when('something*', 'something');

Route::get('/something', 'Frontend\HomeController@index');
```